# How to play Battlefield2 after the shutdown of Gamespy?

Tags: battlefield-2

Since Gamespy shutted down the Battlefield2 Master servers, the vanilla game is not anymore able to authenticate users.

Are there any options left to play the game online?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Please be aware that this answer is no longer valid, since as pointed out in [this article](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2017/10/ea-shuts-down-fan-run-servers-for-older-battlefield-games/), this site has been taken down.**

**Yup, there still are!**

There is a site dedicated to hosting BF2 servers. It can be found here.

Once there, create an account (using the same one you used to use on BF2 before), then download their client and use that.